# Haskell-mode reports "Can't find the prompt"---what could be wrong?

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

When I run `C-c C-l` haskell-mode reports "Can't find the prompt".

My questions are as follows:

- how would I go about debugging this problem? "Can't find the prompt" in itself is probably too little information, so how would I go about finding what the underlying problem is?
- what kinds of issues are likely to be responsible for this error?

Comment: This question doesn't have many details to solve the problem.  Any chance you could provide more information about your setup?  Things like Haskell version, emacs version, OS, and the steps you followed to set up haskell-mode.

Comment: I was explicitly not providing this information, to keep the question more general.

Comment: The problem is that you've said not much more than "haskell-mode doesn't work, why?"  This makes it hard to know what is actually causing the error, it could be any of a number of reasons, and having others try to guess what that reason is would not be very constructive.  Additionally, your recent answer should probably be either a comment or edited into your question, since it is not an answer but more context as to what is going wrong.

Comment: I understand. I'll rephrase the question to be more open.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of your `*Messages*` buffer, clues are usually hidden there, though since sometimes they arise when you first load up Emacs, they can be difficult to find.  You might be getting the error because your haskell-mode process has not even started, as was the case for [this fellow](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/267).

Answer (score 0):

Just for an additional thing to check, on MacOs I was stymied by this error until I realized that I hadn't completely set up my xCode, which I found when I tried to run ghci at the terminal and got an xcode licensing prompt.